# How to draw a cross section of an engine in TikZ

Tags: latex, tikz

I would like to convert the following picture, which is a cross section of an engine, into a TikZ code:

[image: picture]

- How to start with this picture?
- How to draw the walls and pipes in an easy way?
- How to draw the oil (the hatched area)?

Answer (score 0):

> How to draw the oil (the hatched area)?

One way may be to use `pattern=north east lines` from `patterns` library described at page 730 of the [**PGF Manual**](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [pattern=north east lines] (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,6);
\draw  (0,10) -- (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Better, related: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/supersonic-nozzle/